# Cursor to execute t-sql create view statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, dynamic-sql

I'm looking to migrate several SQL views from one database to another. Both databases definitions are identical, so I should not have to worry about compatibility issues. I will have to perform this task on several client systems so I am looking to automate it instead of using the 'Script View As' option and manually duplicating each view.

I am brand new to cursors, so I apologize if this is a terribly simple request but I have tried several approaches and gotten nowhere.  My searches of this site and others have been similarly fruitless. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @view nvarchar(max)
declare @dbname nvarchar(30)
set @dbname = 'DatabaseName'


DECLARE cCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views
where TABLE_NAME like '%MyCriteria%'

OPEN cCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor into @view
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    set @sql  = 'USE ' + @dbname + ' GO ' + @view
    execute @sql
    FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor into @view
END
close cCursor
deallocate cCursor
```

I am getting an error message upon execution that says: 
    Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
    The name 'USE DATA14 GO CREATE VIEW
        .... is not a valid identifier.

where the .... represents the create view statement I fetched from Information schema.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I tried another approach that does not rely on cursors and I believe I am closer, but I am still getting errors that have me baffled:

```
use SourceDB
go

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = N''

select @sql = @sql + 'USE DestDB' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +                         s.definition + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
from sys.sql_modules as s
inner join sys.objects as o
on s.object_id = o.object_id
where o.type_desc = 'VIEW'
and s.definition like '%MyCriteria%'

exec data14..sp_executesql @sql
--select @sql
```

The text of the error message is:
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
    Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
    Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
    'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
    Incorrect syntax near 'GO'...... 
and so on and so forth for each view in the list

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Powershell. There are many ways to do it, I personally like to make a file for each script, and I am making an assumption that the views do not already exist in the new database. So this probably will not work verbatim, but should get you pointed in the right direction.

- Create an export folder on the server (C:\Temp\Views)
- Open the source server in the object explorer.
- Navigate to the source database (/Databases/{DatabaseName})
- Right click on 'Views' and select 'Start Powershell'
- Run the following command which will create a file for each view:

  `ls | ? { $_.name -match "MyCriteria" } | %{ $_.scriptheader(0) + $_.textbody > "C:\temp\views\$($_.Schema).$($_.name).sql" }`
- Import the scripts into another database with

  `ls "C:\temp\views" | %{ invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $_.fullname -database "DatabaseName" }`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but I don't think this will work for me.  I know less about Powershell than I do about cursors so reworking this to fit my needs will be overly time consuming.  Also, if I understand correctly, this will mean creating the directory, running each of the statements in the console, and then cleaning up the directory.  This reduces the amount of manual labor but still leaves more steps than is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're looking for, you have to nest your dynamic SQL within dynamic SQL...

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(30)
SET @dbname = 'DatabaseName'
SET @sql = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql + '
EXEC ' + @dbname + '.sys.sp_executesql N''' + REPLACE(VIEW_DEFINITION, '''', '''''') + ''''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views
WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%table%'

EXEC (@sql);
```

There is a catch though.
The double dynamic sql needs to be double escaped. Hence the REPLACE above.

By the way... The correct syntax for executing dynamic SQL  is EXEC (@SQL) -- Note the brackets
Without the brackets, you're telling the server to execute a procedure. Hence the reason for your first error

Hope that helps